# What is the Plane Shift series considered?

Tags: dnd-5e, mtg-plane-shift

Wizards of the Coast has released multiple *Magic: the Gathering* supplements for *Dungeons & Dragons* (not including the *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica*) as part of the *Plane Shift* PDF series.

What would these be considered? Would they be considered homebrew? Or would they be more akin to the likes of *The Tortle Package* or *Locathah Rising*?

On a further note, are the *Plane Shift* PDFs Adventurers League-compatible?

Answer (score 15):

### They're untested, unsupported material that happens to be published by WOTC.

Starting with *Kaladesh*, the item descriptions on DMsGuild have contained this:

> The game mechanics in this supplement are usable in your D&D campaign but are not fully tempered by playtests and design iterations. For these reasons, material in this supplement is not legal in D&D Organized Play events.

It's similar to the disclaimer found on Unearthed Arcana articles:

> The material in Unearthed Arcana is presented for playtesting and to spark your imagination. These game mechanics are in draft form, usable in your D&D campaign but not refined by final game design. They are not officially part of the game. For these reasons, material in this column is not legal in D&D Adventurers League events.

Answer (score 5):

Anything produced and published by Wizards of the Coast certainly can’t be considered “homebrew,” it is the very epitome of ... whatever the opposite is, “workbrew?” perhaps. “Homebrew” refers to fan efforts, stuff done by a few people, casually, in their free time, and usually not sold. While homebrew can certainly be quite polished, when you do things like create a company for the work to fall under, purchase art and other assets for it, have it professionally type-set, and offer it for sale, you aren’t talking about “homebrew.” When you’re talking about a major multinational corporation with a budget in the millions, like Wizards of the Coast, you *definitely* aren’t talking about homebrew.

However, the Plane Shift products are also not to the same caliber as most other 5e supplements. They are primarily a passion project for some Wizards of the Coast employees. The projects working on them don’t seem to enjoy the same budget or priority that “real” supplements do, and they don’t get a full team working on them. This makes them somewhat similar to *Unearthed Arcana* material, though they are “final” in ways that *Unearthed Arcana* material is often not.

Plane Shift material is not allowed in Adventurer’s League.

Comment: I was curious about who besides Wyatt worked on these... It looks like Zendikar and Innistrad solely credit James Wyatt as writer and Adam Paquette as cover artist. Kaladesh says the same, and adds that it was edited by Scott Fitzgerald Gray. Amonkhet says it was written by Wyatt with Ashlie Hope, with cover art by Titus Lunter, and editing by Gray. Ixalan has Wyatt as writer and Tyler Jacobson as cover artist, and was edited by Gray. Dominaria was written by James Wyatt with Ashlie Hope, cover art by Jacobson, and editing by Gray. (The *X Marks the Spot* adventure credits several others.)