# What flying races are there?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, flight

As we're getting to higher levels I think a flying race may no longer be as much of an issue, of course I'll double check with my DM before using one.

I was unable to find a list of the flying-capable races though.

So far I know about these:

- Aarakocra
- Fairy
- Winged Tiefling
- Owlin
- Aasimar (limited)

Kobold has a note about Urds (Winged Kobolds) but there doesn't seem to be an actual variant racial trait. I guess the DM might allow it as a replacement for Pack Tactics maybe?

Is there any other race capable of flight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The only one you missed is a Lineage character with a flying speed.

The Lineages (Dhampir, Hexblood, Reborn) from *Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft* can have a flying speed if their original race had a flying speed, i.e. was one of the races you listed in your question. They all have the Ancestral Legacy trait, which says:

> ##### Ancestral Legacy
>
> If you replace a race with this lineage, you can keep the following elements of that race: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

These are the only ones not included in your question. So the full list of races with a flying speed is:

- Aarakocra (*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*, *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*)
- Owlin (*Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos*)
- Fairy (*The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*)
- Variant Tiefling (*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*)
- Lineage (Dhampir, Hexblood, or Reborn), with one of the above as the original race (*Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft*)

With lineages, there is some ambiguity surrounding the armor restrictions that come with the flying speeds the original races have. This ambiguity is discussed in this Q&A: [Can a former Aarakocra turned lineage fly while wearing armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185330/can-a-former-aarakocra-turned-lineage-fly-while-wearing-armor)

#### Honorable Mentions

As you mentioned, Aasimar (Protector subrace only, doesn't transfer to a lineage) have an ability to provide limited flight. The Gem Dragonborn from *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* have a limited flight ability similar to the Protector Aasimar. Air Genasi can cast *levitate* once per long rest, regardless of class. And finally, the Simic Hybrid race from *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica* can take the Manta Glide ability, which states:

> You have ray-like fins that you can use as wings to slow your fall or allow you to glide. When you fall and aren’t incapacitated, you can subtract up to 100 feet from the fall when calculating falling damage, and you can move up to 2 feet horizontally for every 1 foot you descend.

It isn't exactly flying, more like [*falling with style*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhVLgTsoMhQ).

As for kobolds, there is unfortunately no official kobold variant with a flying speed.

Comment: There's also the Avariel Elf Unearthed Arcana and a few from the Planeshifts

Comment: @Exempt-Medic If that UA makes it to print I'll include it :P (and the planeshift material is basically 1st party homebrew.)

Comment: Is there a way to combine a Lineage with another race in dndbeyond's character builder?

Comment: @enumag I haven’t played around with lineages on DDB yet, but I can look into it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yeah, I was actually hoping you'd make your own edit instead. Didn't want to change your text though. Thanks!
I tried Lineages on DDB earlier and couldn't get it to work. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @nick012000 As I mentioned above, Planeshift material is not "official" material at this point. See this Q&A: [What is the Plane Shift series considered?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169310)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov The OP didn't ask you to restrict yourself to the official books. The unofficial ones published by WotC should still count, even if they're not AL legal.

Comment: @nick012000 Official material is the default assumption. It will take meta consensus to convince me otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a frame challenge.  You asked about official flying races, but is it possible that you just want to fly, and that the race need not be official, or that the feature could come from another source?

Two things hinted at in your question led me to propose these two solutions, in addition to the existing excellent answer.

**1) Work with the DM on a homebrew race**

You mention getting a winged kobold by replacing pack tactics with flight.  Negotiating with the DM to realize your vision makes perfect sense.  You may be able to take the stats of an existing flying race and reskin it to match your concept, or, as you suggest, trade a racial feature for flight.

**2) Get flight through another method**

Is it possible you just want to fly, and it doesn't have to be a racial characteristic?

You said:

> As we're getting to higher levels I think a flying race may no longer be as much of an issue

That suggests to me that the party as a whole is increasing in level, and new characters come in at or approximately at the level of existing characters.  Often when that is the case, DMs grant one or more magic items to a new character to put them on par with the existing party.

If that is the case, you might be able to negotiate with the DM to give your new non-flying character a magic item that grants flying.  Two popular ones are:

- *[broom of flying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/broom-of-flying)*
- *[winged boots](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/winged-boots)*

There are many others.  If you want to pursue this, you might be able to talk to your DM to work something out.

Comment: "You mention getting a winged kobold by replacing pack tactics with flight." Just eyeballing the balance there, that might actually be a pretty fair trade. Pack Tactics is a really good feature, and I might even say the tradeoff makes the kobold a bit weaker at higher levels as flying becomes generally more accessible. In tier 1 and maybe tier 2 play, I'd say it's pretty even as flying is harder to come by at that level of play.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov My thought exactly. I don't think a winged kobold should just get the feature on top - in other cases like Winged Tiefling it replaces something so trading pack tactics for it makes sense to me. Also since winged kobold are despised by normal kobolda I don't think they'd be let to learn the pack tactics with others so it makes sense in that way too. (Although Winged Kobold as monster does in fact have pack tactics.)