# Can you build a lineage from a lineage?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races

While searching for more details on the limitations imposed on ancestral lineages, I came across [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197089/what-flying-races-are-there/197091?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C16.8769#197091) from Thomas Markov where he included Fairies and Dhampirs as possible sources for flight speed, but I remember reading somewhere that lineages (such as the Reborn) cannot be based on other lineages.

From what I recall, there were arguments about balancing characters with too many lineages, though I don't get the problem if an Aarakocra Dhampir becomes Reborn as it gains no additional speeds or proficiencies... So could someone explain if/why this might be an issue?

*As an aside, if it is possible for a fairy or a plasmoid to be reborn, would they retain their creature types? Or become humanoid in the process?*

Comment: Personally, I feel like the meta-commentary explaining why you're asking it as its own question is unnecessary – it *is* a new question (though it may still be worth linking to that original Q&A that made you wonder about it).

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike I dunno why you and he are on strike, though I did notice his name reflected so. As for what I meant, as of, but could not remember the verbiage

Comment: @V2Blast ah ok, I thought it sounded more like a small addendum or clarification than one worthy of being considered a whole question. But I do trust your judgement and will modify it in a bit

Comment: @VictorB Edited to reflect your intent.  Our strikes are in support of the general stack [moderator strike](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12444/23547).

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike Thanks for the info. I had no idea this was happening, and don't understand SO's logic... More and more info is coming out on Chat GPT that shows how biased, misguided, and misinformed it is (to the point some doctors showed that it could lead to horrible misuse of medicines).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Creating “a lineage from a lineage from a race” is the same as creating “a lineage from a race”.

The lineage feature Ancestral Legacy reads:

> If you replace a race with this lineage, you can keep the following elements of that race: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

Whether or not you can replace a lineage with a lineage doesn’t matter, this feature ensures that only the listed features from the first lineage are brought over, which are exactly the listed features from the original race. *It is as though you only selected one lineage*. So it doesn’t matter, making a lineage from a lineage doesn’t do anything different than just choosing one lineage.

As an aside, Ancestral Legacy also says what happens when you choose fairy or plasmoid as the base race for a lineage.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply, though could you elaborate on that last point? I found your original reply looking up if a wood elf's walk speed counted, and can't seem to find any information on Reborn Fairies

Comment: @VictorB There isn’t much else to say. Ancestral Legacy tells you what features you keep, so you only keep those features.

Comment: ah ok. I thought you meant there was one addressing lineages directly.